# Responsive divs in angular material

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am not able to make the divs responsive. How do I make them responsive? The content boxes should appear one below the other when size is reduced.  Below is the code that is taken from an another codepen and angular material website.

```
         <h1>User List</h1>
  <div class='md-padding' layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <div class="parent" layout="column" ng-repeat="user in users" flex>
        <md-card>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="md-card-image" alt="user avatar">
          <md-card-content>
            <h2>{{user}}</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
          </md-card-content>
          <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button>Save</md-button>
            <md-button>View</md-button>
          </div>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </md-content>
```

Link to code pen 
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/vijayphani/pen/JRRoRd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ORRWGp?editors=1100)

The [information in the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) is quite informative about responsive design.

Markup

```
    <div class='md-padding' layout="row" flex>
        <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" flex> <!-- define layout here -->
            <div class="parent" layout="column" ng-repeat="user in users" flex>
                <md-card>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="md-card-image" alt="user avatar">
                    <md-card-content>
                        <h2 class="user">{{user}}</h2>
                        <p class="userInfo">Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </md-card-content>
                    <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                        <md-button>Save</md-button>
                        <md-button>View</md-button>
                    </div>
                </md-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```